# How I can read some specific data from a file that contain different types of data?

Tags: java, io

I need to write some data about several companies into a binary file; the data includes name of companies (String), year of incorporation (int), and revenue this year (double). Write data would be not trouble to me, but I don't know how to read some specific data from a the binary file; for example, if I have name of a company, I need to return the the other data about the company. So far, I only know to read all the data or maybe line by line in a binary file. Can someone suggest which class or method I need to use to do so?

Comment: Read all the companies until you find the one with the given name? Or read everything and put that in a `Map<String, Company>` in memory, and use this in-memory data structure to find a company by name? Or use a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about
[serialization/deserialization of objects in Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm).
Serialize list of companies (e.g. `ArrayList<Company> companies`) then simply deserialize it, so you can use the same list of companies again in your code then search through list to find the company you want. Optionally, you can use `Map<String, Company>` as JB Nizet suggests.